# How does grep return a result, then when opened, control+f cannot find?

Tags: string, search, grep, cygwin

I ran the following

```
grep -irln "mold"
```

against a directory using cygwin on my Windows 7 Enterprise machine at work and it found a match in a particular pdf file. However, when I open the file via adobe or chrome and do control+f and search for mold, no results are found. This PDF has been through an OCR service. So I guess my question is how is it possible for grep to return results but then do a ctrl+f on the open file and get nothing?

Comment: pdf is not plaintext file, is it? even if you OCR-ed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are misunderstanding that grep looks for every occurance in a file and that a PDF file is a written in markup language to render the graphical appearence of text and images.
Using a very simple text file as example

```
$ cat << EOF > example.txt
> one dog
> two cats
> three chickens
> EOF
```

we convert it to postscript and than to pdf

```
$ a2ps example.txt -o example.ps
[example.txt (plain): 1 page on 1 sheet]
[Total: 1 page on 1 sheet] saved into the file `example.ps'
$ ps2pdf example.ps example.pdf
```

so we have 3 files with the same text, but the postscript and the PDF have their specific markup languange around the original text.
Now if we ask grep to look for the chicken

```
$ grep chicken example.*
example.ps:(three chickens) N
example.txt:three chickens
```

you can see that the PDF file does not contain `chicken` as plain text. This is because the original text is compressed inside the PDF.

Your result of `mold` is a false positive. The text inside the PDF is compressed and grep can not find it.

Comment: Thank you, it seems I did misunderstand it. Thank you for explaining clearly and with an example, much appreciated.